# Sales Journal Setup in OpenERP 7.0

Tags: odoo

I notice in Bahmni by default all products will have Income Account : 200000 Product Sales. Then in the Sales Journal, Default Debit Account and Default Credit Account : 200000 Product Sales.

My question would be on the Sales Journal. How do I set the Default Debit Account and Default Credit Account when I have more than one Income Account (from different Department)?

Comment: And again that's a functional question. StackOverflow is for programming questions. Please ask your question in the [official Odoo forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1).

Answer (score 0):

For setting up accounts you can define records in '**ir.property**' i.e. **Company Property**